# All my Acers refuse to install any kind of ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, acer

All of my Acer laptops can not install ubuntu or its family with all the same error: "Can not run grub-install /dev/dm-0" but why dm-0? it was never made or used so of course i select "grub-install /dev/sda" but it freezes the same with /dev/sdb, it doesnt matter what distro of ubuntu: ubuntu mate, kubuntu, ubuntu they all do the same but mint and arch work.... also my dvd's are working on dell's and others, so what am i doing wrong?!

Comment: are you installing efi or legacy?

Comment: legacy BIOS but i can change it to efi if it helps?

Comment: It might work better in EFI mode. But some models of ACER laptops require "trusted execution" to be set in the firmware settings

Comment: It failed, but why does it try to install  it on /dev/dm-0? when i slect install on /dev/sda an press OK it does nothing like you never even came close to clicking OK.......

Comment: I'm not sure what a /dm divice is ... is the SATA controller set to AHCI or RAID/IDE?

Comment: I do not know either it seems to do with a device mapper with LVM so i tried disabling the LVM. Now re-installing again......

Comment: this suggest that the SATA controller is set to RAID.

Comment: I did that now it says it is done installing but i get the error that it couldn't install grub on /dev/sda.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70398/discussion-between-ravery-and-yoran-jansen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it with some help of the user ravery.
I ran this script (I did a reboot into DVD after install, then ran this):

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt

for dir in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do
    mount --bind $dir /mnt$dir
done

chroot /mnt

update-grub

grub-install /dev/sda

exit

shutdown -h now
```

Credits:

Internet - `for dir` command

ravery - mount /dev/sda1 /mnt AFTER the `for dir` command

Me - everything else